# Loop on a PHP array and ignore some entries

Tags: php

I get some random PHP arrays generated by a backend, and I want to loop in it, and ignore all entries where weight > 5000.
Some array example:

```html
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#72 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(2) "80"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-02 11:49:27"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#68 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(4) "6760"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-04 14:30:25"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#63 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(4) "1360"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-04 14:56:21"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#122 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(4) "1040"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-25 16:52:25"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
```

And my desired output will be:

```html
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#72 (3) {
    ["weight"]=>
    string(2) "6760"
    ["added_date"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-02 11:49:27"
    ["etid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
```

How will look a PHP for loop to only filter the array values with weight >5000. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Sounds pretty straight forward. What is your question?

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/ru/class.filteriterator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many approaches exist, but this is probably the most simple and straight forward:

```
<?php
$outputArray = [];
foreach ($inputArray as $inputElement) {
  if (5000 <= (int)$inputElement->weight) {
    $outputArray[] = $inputElement;
  }
}
var_dump($outputArray);
```

Comment: @JeanDoux The logic was the wrong way 'round: the OP wants entries _below_ 5000. So an elemtnshould be accepted in the output array if its weight is _below_ 5000.

Comment: the Op wants above 5000, look at his example.

Comment: @JeanDoux Thanks for pointing that out. I could have sworn it was the other way 'round... my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter fonction :

```
function BigWeight($value)
{
    return (is_object($value) && $value->weight >= 5000);
}

 $filtered_array = array_filter($your_array, "BigWeight");
 print_r($filtered_array);
```